# Running a C Program in Bash Script

Tags: c, bash

When I run a C program in this bash script it returns the error.

```
ssh -n -f *.*.*.* "cd /home/sth/remote && echo "$1" && det=$(./ossec-rootcheck)">/home/sthh/res
```

Error:

```
 ./ossec-rootcheck: No such file or directory
```

I want to ssh to a remote machine and then run a program on it. I know that this file is located in that path because when I edit it as you see, it works.

```
ssh -n -f *.*.*.* "cd /home/sth/remote && echo "$1" && ./ossec-rootcheck">/home/sthh/res
```

and as it `echo $1` I can see that it does `cd /home/sth/remote` right. But I want the return value of that program to be stored in a variable,for example `det`.

Comment: I believe the problem is that the shell evaluates `det=$(./ossec-rootcheck)` before it does the `cd` because it is evaluating the shell parameters in the expression before it executes it. Why do you need the result in `det`?

Comment: The C program returns 0 or 1, if `det` equals 1 rest of script would do something.

Comment: You need to escape the dollar like this: `det=\$(./ossec-rootcheck)` so that the command runs on the remote machine.

Comment: @mbratch: So there's no way to get return value of a C program in bash script? I don't want what is sent to `stdout`.

Comment: @dogbane: post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the return code or exit code of the remote code:

```
ssh -n -f *.*.*.* "cd /***/***/remote && echo \"$1\"; ./ossec-rootcheck; echo \$?">/home/ossl7/res
```

To capture errors as well:

```
ssh -n -f *.*.*.* "exec 2>&1; cd /***/***/remote && echo \"$1\"; ./ossec-rootcheck; echo \$?">/home/ossl7/res
```

Also, you probably need to omit `&& echo \"$1\"` when you find it to be working already. And you could just use single quotes for that:

```
ssh -n -f *.*.*.* 'cd /***/***/remote; ./ossec-rootcheck; echo $?' >/home/ossl7/res
```

Or

```
ssh -n -f *.*.*.* 'exec 2>&1; cd /***/***/remote; ./ossec-rootcheck; echo $?' >/home/ossl7/res
```

Comment: To store it in a variable: `det=$(ssh -n -f *.*.*.* 'cd /***/***/remote; ./ossec-rootcheck; echo $?')`

Comment: @ konsolebox:What about the stdout output of the program that I want to be stored in a file `res`?

Comment: If you want to copy the output, just do `echo "$det" > res` after that.

Comment: Also, do you mean stdout as both messages for `stdout` and `stderr`? Or just the result code?

Comment: This is my first comment that "konsolebox" has replied,I had to edit  that so I post it again----->To store the exit code in a variable I did so: `ssh -n -f *.*.*.* "cd /***/***/remote && ./ossec-rootcheck; det=\$(\$?)">/***/***/res` but the error `bash: 0: command not found...` apeared.In fact I want the `stdout` output of the C program in file res and the exit or return code in variable `det`. and I want det to be accessible out of ssh session of that remote machine, I mean in the rest of script.Next line of script would be : `if [ "$det" -eq "1" ] ; then echo "DETECTED!"`

Comment: @ konsolebox:Yes, I mean `stdout` and `stderr`, my program does some `printf` and return an exit code as 0 or 1 I want both of these outputs one of them in a file `res` and the latter in the variable `det`.

Comment: You can redirect both your stdout and stderr to fd 2, then use fd 1 for the exit code:

`det=$(ssh -n -f *.*.*.* 'cd /***/***/remote; ./ossec-rootcheck >&2; echo $?' 2>/home/ossl7/res)`

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh -n -f *.*.*.* "cd /home/sth/remote; echo "$1"; ./ossec-rootcheck || do_your_work">/home/sthh/res
```

You don't have to store it in a variable.

|| executes do_your_work if the exit status of ossec-rootcheck != 0

If you want to store the numeric exit status in a variable, or echo it, you can do (with proper escaping):

```
./ossec-rootcheck; ecode=$?; echo $ecode
```